# Is there a way to read bin and mark files in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way to read bin and mark files in clikchouse ?

Every Column has a bin and mark files in the clickhouse data directory. I want to read it , for Better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Reading mark file is quite easy, while bin files are relatively complicated. It has compressed blocks, different types of compressions are used, inside - just a raw binary values one after another. The best option to read that is using ClickHouse itself.

For more detail i recommend to read the sources.